# Dynamic block should not render when map is not present in Terraform

Tags: terraform

Here's my AWS security group resource:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "db-sgs" {
  for_each = var.dbs

  name   = each.value.security_group.name
  vpc_id = "test"

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = can(each.value.security_group) ? each.value.security_group.ingress : {}

    content {
      description     = ingress.value.description
      from_port       = 5432
      to_port         = 5432
      protocol        = "tcp"
      security_groups = [ingress.value.source_sg]
    }
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Corresponding values:

```
dbs:
  test:
    ...
    security_group:
      name: test
```

So basically where there is no `ingress` stanza dynamic block should be not generated, It should however when values would look like this:

```
dbs:
  test:
    ...
    security_group:
      name: test
      ingress:
        test:
          source_sg: sg-12df601c
          description: Test Access
```

Using first values I getting error: `Cannot use a null value in for_each.`

But why is that? The false value should be `{}`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe try `can(each.value.security_group) && each.value.security_group.ingress != null ? each.value.security_group.ingress : {}`.

Comment: Do you have a typo where it should be `can(each.value.security_group.ingress)`? If `security_group` is possible to be undefined, then assigning its `name` attribute to the `name` parameter in the resource would consistently error.

Comment: @MarkoE `each.value.security_group.ingress != null ? each.value.security_group.ingress : {}` did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A concise way to handle this would be to use `try` instead of `can`, which will provide a fallback if either of the levels of traversal fail:

```
  for_each = try(each.value.security_group.ingress, {})
```

Both `each.value.security_group` and `each.value.security_group.ingress` could potentially fail, so the above `try` will intercept both of those failures and return `{}` instead.